# Entity Framework Core 3.1 Enum Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'EnumValue' to data type int

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm using Entity Framework Core 3.1 and trying to do a simple query on an enum property in my entity in my localdb and I keep getting this error:

> Enum conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Accountant' to data type int

Entity:

```cs
public class DemoEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Enum - Position:

```cs
public enum Position
{
    [Display(Name = "Accountant")]
    Accountant,
    [Display(Name = "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)")]
    ChiefExecutiveOfficer,
    [Display(Name = "Integration Specialist")]
    IntegrationSpecialist,
    [Display(Name = "Junior Technical Author")]
    JuniorTechnicalAuthor,
    [Display(Name = "Pre Sales Support")]
    PreSalesSupport,
    [Display(Name = "Sales Assistant")]
    SalesAssistant,
    [Display(Name = "Senior Javascript Developer")]
    SeniorJavascriptDeveloper,
    [Display(Name = "Software Engineer")]
    SoftwareEngineer
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class DemoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DemoDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<DemoEntity> Demos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //var converter = new ValueConverter<Position, string>(
        //                    v => v.ToString(),
        //                    v => (Position)Enum.Parse(typeof(Position), v));

        //var converter = new EnumToStringConverter<Position>();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<DemoEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Position);
            //.HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)")
            //.HasConversion<string>();
            //.HasConversion(converter);
    }
}
```

I tried adding value conversions:

1. `.HasConversion<string>()` - didn't work
2. `.HasConversion(converter)` - didn't work

When I query the table as follows I'm getting the conversion error

```cs
try
{
    var test = await query.Where(x => x.Position.Equals(Position.Accountant)).ToListAsync();
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    //throw;
}
```

The `Position` is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in my database.

[image]

[image]

Am I missing anything simple? Not able to figure where I'm going wrong. Please assist.

Comment: `.HasConversion<string>()` is the correct mapping. What "didn't work"?

Comment: I tried  adding`.HasConversion<string>()`. When the query gets executed I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I modified the query to `query.Where(x => x.Position.Equals(Position.Accountant.ToString())).ToListAsync()`. Now the query executes but I get zero results. Any idea?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to reproduce it. Yet another EFC bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the underlying database column type is string, association value converter is the correct mapping (by default EF Core maps `enum`s to `int`).

So something like this is a must

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DemoEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.Position)
    .HasConversion<string>();
```

Which leads to the original problem. Looks like you are hitting EF Core query translation bug - the expression

```
x.Position.Equals(Position.Accountant)
```

is wrongly translated to something like

```
WHERE [d].[Position] = 0
```

instead of expected

```
WHERE [d].[Position] = N'Accountant'
```

The solution is to use comparison operators (`==` and `!=`) instead of `Equals`:

```
x.Position == Position.Accountant
```

which translates correctly.

In general avoid `Equals` (and `Compare`, `CompareTo` etc.) methods when there is corresponding C# operator.

Comment: Great answer but I somehow had to do the opposite, use the .Equals instead of ==